# Deserialize complex JSON object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize a complex JSON object as follows:

```
public class StationaryOsbtacle
{
    public float latitude { get; set; }
    public float longitude { get; set; }
    public float cylinder_radius { get; set; }
    public float cylinder_height { get; set; }
}

public class MovingObstacle
{
    public float latitude { get; set; }
    public float longitude { get; set; }
    public float altitude_msl { get; set; }
    public float sphere_radius { get; set; }
}

public class RootObjectMovingObstacle
{
    public List<StationaryOsbtacle> stationary_osbtacles { get; set; }
    public List<MovingObstacle> moving_obstacles { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON data is:

```
{"stationary_osbtacles": [
    {
      "latitude": 33.833920,
      "longitude": -90.175781,
      "cylinder_radius": 20,
      "cylinder_height": 200
    }
  ],
  "moving_obstacles": [
    {
      "latitude": 33.833920,
      "longitude": -90.175781,
      "altitude_msl": 200,
      "sphere_radius": 20
    }
  ]}
```

How can I deserialize every property separately (latitude, longitude and so on)?

In the end I am trying view any variable by a label I am using the following code and get a list
This code is inside a timer and I dont know what is the size of the array

```
        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + Ip.ToString() + ":" + Port.ToString() + "....."); // Create a request to get obstacles
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar; //set container for HttpWebRequest 

        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse(); // Get the response.

        using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))

        {
              var outObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectMovingObstacle>(reader.ReadToEnd());
              my_label_latitude.Text = outObject.stationary_osbtacles.......?
        }
```

How do I keep from here display any real variable on a label?

Comment: What is the error you get when you DeserializeObject?

Comment: add some sample json. I think you ll find that int isnt the best match for lat/long

Comment: @Praveen, I dont get any error because I dont know how to do that.

Comment: @Ewan I added the sample JSON, it consists of floats I will change it.

Comment: i mean a sample with real data

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectMovingObstacle>(...)` as you did in the prev question?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Newtonsoft JSON engine:

```
var yourClass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
   .DeserializeObject<RootObjectMovingObstacle>(...);
```

There are tons of examples on SO and google.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse any json string into object using simple `dynamic` object using Newtonsoft JSON library:

```
JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(strJson)) { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None };
dynamic jsonObj = JObject.Load(jsonReader);
```

Comment: why so complicated? isn't it easier to just go
    `dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);`

Comment: The OP already has a class definition for `StationaryOsbtacle`. Deserialising as `dynamic` is a very drastic (and dirty) choice when the data structure is known and static.